# Json decode не работает в чем проблема?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$url = file_get_contents("http://kinopen.tk/");
$js = json_decode($url, true);
print_r($js);
```

На том сайте массив и echo json_encode, почему не работает его вывод ?

Comment: распечатайте $url

Comment: @splash58 , как распечатать ?

Comment: всё работает http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a53ea13363b325be4531e50b8d3513dc4f5ce374    https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzNMj.png

Comment: @СергейМишин, я же не буду копировать json с url и вставлять как вы ) Нужно чтобы он именно с url декодировал

Comment: может быть у вас не работает `file_get_contents`? Например там, где вы его используете данный функционал заблокирован? может  в `url` у вас ничего нет или false  (Функция возвращает прочтенные данные или false в случае возникновения ошибки.)

Comment: @СергейМишин, у вас там не file_get_contents а строка

Comment: @GamerOK потому что в песочнице нельзя использовать `file_get_contents` :) Читайте коммент выше. Возможно у вас проблема именно с ней. Нужно отследить ошибку и возможно функцию использовать по-другому  https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: @СергейМишин, если вывести echo $url; то выводит без проблем, но не декодирует почему то (

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38469427/php-file-get-contents-with-json-decode-not-working-together
работает, если сделать
$js = json_decode(trim($url, "\xEF\xBB\xBF"), true);

Comment: ```
php 1.php
Array
(
    [test] => Музыка
    [tr] => Поле
)
```

Comment: @AlexeyLakris, \xEF\xBB\xBF можно спросить это что

Comment: @AlexeyLakris, спасибо вам огромное )

Comment: ну какой-то мусор, умные люди знают откуда он, я - нет :)

Comment: @GamerOK это значит, что либо ваш файл, либо тот,, что отдаёт json имеет кодировку UTF-8 with BOM, это служебные символы кодировки. Чтобы от них избавиться надо сохранять файлы как UTF-8 without BOM. В Notepad++ есть такая функция например (https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtAcU.png). Во всех адекватных IDE по умолчанию без BOM если кодировка UTF-8. Но где-то ещё это появляется

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Маркер_последовательности_байтов   ну и если в поиск вбить "UTF-8 с BOM" можно всякого почитать. В целом BOM давно не используется и не нужен